# How many sources can be detected in ICA?

Tags: independent-component-analysis

Is there an upper (or even lower?) limit for the number of sources which can be identified in [ICA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_component_analysis)?

Comment: Yes: the number of observations you have. (That’s in the Introduction section of the ICA article you linked.)

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy True :) I can hardly imagine, does this really mean, that I could distinguish three speakers from each other, when I have three data points?